# Turning off detection between sprites

Tags: sprite-kit

I have two  phyicsbodies in my spritekit game which are colliding and I am having a little difficulty getting them to stop.

I am posting the physics code for them below.
Problem is when the swarm touches my coins it pushes it, not exactly sure why since as far as my know my enemy is told to only contact with the player and my coin is told to only contact with the wall and the player (correct me if im wrong)

(P.S I commented out the collisionBitMask for the coin because when I dont my coins fall thru my walls )

Thanks

1St sprite

```
   enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Swarm"];
enemy.physicsBody =
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:enemy.size];
enemy.physicsBody.dynamic=NO;
enemy.name=@"Eagle";
enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PCFallersCategory;
     // enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =
   //  PCPlayerCategory;
     enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PCPlayerCategory;
      enemy.physicsBody.restitution=0;
      enemy.physicsBody.friction=0;
```

2nd Sprite.

```
self.name = @"coin";
CGFloat minDiam = MIN(self.size.width, self.size.height);
minDiam = MAX(minDiam-8, 8);

self.physicsBody =
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:minDiam/2.0];
self.physicsBody.dynamic=YES;
self.physicsBody.restitution =0;
    self.physicsBody.friction = 0;
    self.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PCCollectableCategotry;
   //self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =PCPlayerCategory;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PCPlayerCategory|PCWallCategory;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the collisionBitMask to 0.

```
enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/collisionBitMask)

> When two physics bodies contact each other, a collision may occur.
>   This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category
>   mask by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a
>   non-zero value, then this body is affected by the collision. Each body
>   independently chooses whether it wants to be affected by the other
>   body. For example, you might use this to avoid collision calculations
>   that would make negligible changes to a body’s velocity.
>
> The default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set).

This means that by default, an SKPhysicsBody is configured to collide with all objects.

Comment: but i still want my coin to colide with my player as well as my enemy

Comment: You do understand the difference between collisionBitMask and contactTestBitmask?

Comment: The collisionBitMask prevents prevents two physicsBodies from overlapping each other, whereas, the contactTestBitMask specifies the categories for which the contact delegate needs to be called.

Comment: @aksashg I do, I just get confused between collion and contact.